# Dynamically How to append more rows with columns into table using javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to append 3 rows into table with 3 column.I tried the following code,but it's not working.

html Code:

```
  <table width="50%" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="5" class="height">
    </table>
```

javascriptcode:

```
  var table=document.getElementsByClassName('height') ;
  //creating inputfield with attribute
  var newField=document.createElement('input');
  newField.setAttribute('type','text');
  //creating <td> 
  var newTd=document.createElement('td');
  //appending newField into td
  newTd.appendChild(newField);
  //creating <tr> element
  var newTr=document.createElement('tr');
  //appending 3 <td>(newTd) elements,but here 3 <td>'s are not appending
  newTr.appendChild(newTd);
  newTr.appendChild(newTd);
  newTr.appendChild(newTd);
  //the above code was not working,if it works I want to append 3 <tr> into <table>.
```

I don't want to use external libraries(jquery,....) .

thanks

Comment: You cannot append the same element multiple times. Inserting it into the DOM will remove it from its previous position. You will need 3 different elements; call `createElement` 3 times (plus the same thing for the `input`s). Use a loop for that.

Comment: @Bergi Thank you, your comment was very useful. I can't able to accept your comment.

Comment: …because it's only a comment, not a whole answer :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a suggestion:

```
var table = document.getElementsByClassName('height')[0]; //I added [0] here

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    var newField = document.createElement('input');
    newField.setAttribute('type', 'text');
    var newTd = document.createElement('td');
    newTd.appendChild(newField);
    var newTr = document.createElement('tr');
    newTr.appendChild(newTd);

    table.appendChild(newTr);  //you had forgoten this one
}
```

### Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6DHqj/)

Answer (score 0):

See http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/10/06/inside-the-box-with-vanilla-javascript/ and goto to 'The  API' section. This page explains about the default JS table DOM api.
It consists of the following methods:

```
insertRow()
deleteRow()
insertCell()
deleteCell()
createCaption()
deleteCaption()
createTHead()
deleteTHead()
```

Comment: Those will make it a little easier, but please provide an answer where you solve the OP's problem.

Answer (score 0):

Does this solution suits your needs?

```
table.innerHTML = new Array(4).join(
    '<tr>' + new Array(4).join('<td><input type="text" /></td>') + '</tr>'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another try:

```js
var table = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0];
// creates a template row with 3 cells
var tr = document.createElement('tr');
tr.innerHTML = new Array(4).join(
  '<td><input type="text" /></td>'
);
// appends 3 rows to the table by cloning the template row
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  table.appendChild(tr.cloneNode(true));
}
```

```html
<table width="50%" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="5" class="height"></table>
```